# How To Create a CloudTrail for DynamoDb in AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-cloudtrail

In AWS it is indicated that there is support to use Cloudtrail to track events in DynamoDB in the link here.

- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/logging-using-cloudtrail.html

However, in the instructions, there is no option to pick DynamoDB anywhere (only S3 and Lambda options are available) so I am looking for any instructions anywhere on how to track DynamoDb events. Specifically I want to know when a table has been deleted.

- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/awscloudtrail/latest/userguide/cloudtrail-create-a-trail-using-the-console-first-time.html

**Has anyone had any luck?** Thanks!

Comment: DynamoDB now supports data plane CloudTrail events.

Answer (score 0):

The AWS Console displays only S3 and Lambda, since at the moment only those two services are supported for logging data events. E.g. `PutObject` etc.

`DeleteTable` is a management event, and is listed in the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/logging-using-cloudtrail.html) you posted. If you configure your Trail to log all management events, all AWS services you use, including DynamoDB, will be logging these management events.

Just create a new trail, and include all management events. Then in your Trail's event history you will find the events like below.

[image]